# Display table results without repeating certain values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, duplicates

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that joins two tables: one contains a list of vendors and the other contains the products (there's a relationship based on using a vendor_id).  What I am looking to do: query the tables so that it will show me the results without repeating vendor names. So basically, print the company name once...in its respective column, then the next column would display the matching products

This is what my current query looks like--it returns the results I want, but the company names are repeated.

```
select vendor.name as 'Company', product.name as 'Product', 
product.date_added as 'Date Added', product.quantity as 'Inventory'
from vendor
join product
on vendor.vendor_id = product.vendor_id
order by vendor.name asc;
```

Comment: Thats because one vendor may be associated with multiple products and joining one to many will return many rows and thats usual. How do you want to display the data give some example of that with sample data.

Comment: Here's what I'm sort of picturing for an output.  See link: http://s8.postimg.org/p2svtlff9/Untitled.png

Comment: No that can't be done with sql that needs to be done using the application level. In my answer I have added an example to use `group_concat()` you can do it for other columns as well and then in the application level you need to adjust it. SQL is not built to do the way you want.

Comment: Nuts, oh well. Thanks for the input.  Saved me tons of searching that would've gone nowhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** function

```
select 
v.name as 'Company',
group_concat(p.name SEPARATOR '>') as 'Product'
from vendor v 
join product p on p.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
group by v.name
order by  v.name
```